# Error 500 on WordPress 5.3.2 only ony time when first visit

Tags: wordpress, windows-server-2016, http-status-code-500

There is always a 500 error when you first visit the site. But only once, after reloading the page, everything works fine.
WordPress 5.3.2
IIS
Windows Server 2016

Comment: can i have your site url ?

Comment: Check your server error log for more detail or turn on debug configuration.

Comment: The web site is: http://swa.futbol

Comment: I already turn on debug, but don't help me. About server logs, what is you mine, events list of windows?